# font awesome 4.3+ spinner mozilla glitch

Tags: css, animation, font-awesome, fontawesome-4.4.0

While spinning fa-spinner sometimes shows a line around the spinner circle. Glitch seems to appear only in firefox (im using 44.0.2 version). Here's some fiddle:

```css
#spinner {
  font-size: 56px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse" id="spinner"></i>
```

Comment: Could you upload a picture about the glitch because it works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox as well.

Comment: Yeah, for some reasons it works fine on some computers with the same firefox version (might depend on monitor) https://s23.postimg.org/9qkjmp3kb/spinner.jpg

Comment: Tested it on 5 computers. Can not reproduce it on 2 of them.

Comment: Try this #spinner { font-size: 56px;  border: 0; }

Comment: i've tryed it. It is not border/box-shadow/outline. It is most likely either an animation glitch or icon problem.

Comment: Fixed in firefox 46.0.1. No idea what have been changed.